# ajax call, bug with appending results to options

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm not having any truly functional issues with this script but there's a slight bug here that I can't figure out.

The process: The user types in the input field `#productInput`. On each keystroke, the value they've typed thus far is sent to an endpoint via ajax, query results are returned and appended to an `<option>` dropdown for a `<datalist>`. This works but here's the issue:

If I type 'TES' I can see 7 products (TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4, TEST5, TEST6, TEST7). But when I complete the word and type 'TEST', it only shows one or two of those results, even though they all contain the word TEST. Is there an obvious issue here causing this bug that I'm missing?

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function() {

  let _this = $(this);
  let foundOption;
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;

  if (_this.val() === '') {
    return;
  } else if ($('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector).length) {
     console.log("else");
  } else {

    const searchResult = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({ url: '/autocomplete', 
      data: {
        search_result:searchResult
      },
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      type: "POST", 
      success: function (response) {

        console.log(response);
        $("#returnedProducts").empty();

        var result = response.hits.hits;

        //for each result in the object, append to option list
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          $("#returnedProducts").append($("<option/>",
                    {
                        "srindex": i,
                        "data-attributes": JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.frame.group),
                        "data-covers":JSON.stringify(result[i]._source.covers[1]),
                        "value": result[i]._source.group_cover_color,
                        "html": result[i]._source.group_cover_color,
                    }
            ));

        }
    }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the returned result in the F12 inspector?  Maybe you are just receiving exactly the result from the server.  The problem may be on the server side, not the AJAX processing.

Comment: Agree. Since you aren't doing any filtering client side it is likely a back end issue

Comment: Well my console.log for TES and TEST both return an array with the same number of results

Comment: For clarity, can you please post the console log `response` for TES and TEST?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what 2 results? It does sound like a back end issue though

Comment: Ok, when I comment out ```//"value": result[i]._source.group_cover_color,``` it works fine